# Entity Framework Where is my AddOrUpdate function?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working in VS2015 WCF service against a SQL Server 2012 db with Entity Framework 6.1.3

I started out with "Code First from Existing Database" and since then do all edits from CF.

I have basic read write operations working.  I can .Add to a table fine and it works as expected but I can't .AddOrUpdate as I see people talking about because it's not in the intellisense dropdown as I type!?

Here's a screen grab...

[image: No .AddOrUpdate]

Comment: Note that using `AddOrUpdate` outside of migrations is not recommended

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's an [`IDbSetExtensions` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.idbsetextensions(v=vs.103).aspx).

You need to add a `using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;` directive.

As explained [here](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/) and in various other sources (just search the web for '"AddOrUpdate" entity framework') this method is meant to be used for seeding only. Don't use it in your application logic.

Comment: ...and just like that my problem is solved!  Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @CodeCaster, adding the namespace resolved my issue to update.

Comment: that was an easy fix. thanks @CodeCaster